# Flask doesn't use my css style specifications

Tags: html, css

I am programming a flask application. In that I have a main html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table generator</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/lib/skeleton/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/lib/skeleton/skeleton.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="/instructions">Instructions</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

for my stylesheet I linked this css file:

```
.navigation {
    list-style-type = none;
}
```

But when I am running the file the list still looks like this:
[image]

I want my list to not have the dots in front. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think that's valid css.  It should be `list-style-type: none;`  (i.e. use a colon, not an equal sign)

Comment: You should always let flask/jinja handle these links. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />`. There's not enough info to know if that alone will fix it, but it's a pattern you should be using

Comment: Does the web server log show a successful GET on the css file?

Comment: How can I get that information

Comment: By the way I exchanged the = with a : and that doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

This code will work, you need to apply that style to the list element itself.

```css
.navigation li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table generator</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/lib/skeleton/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/lib/skeleton/skeleton.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="/instructions">Instructions</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not `.navigation {list-style-type: none;}` instead of applying it to every single child ?

Comment: I tried to copy and run your code exactly how you wrote it but it does not work

Comment: does the "Run code snippet" yield the appropriate results? It's working for me in chrome / IE / FF. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome.